# tapping outside the context menu dismisses it

Tags: android

I have created a context menu. When I click outside this context menu nothing happens. But when I check it for Ice Cream Sandwich phones, menu gets dismissed when I click outside the context menu. How can I avoid this dismissal? Is there any method like `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` as in Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any api to change the behaviour, you will have to create your own dialog to do this.